# Is it access token facebook is static?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

i use open graph for access member to register and login with facebook account in codeigniter, and i have idea to create automatic password with access token for every user, but i dont exactly know is it access token facebook is static or will different every time user access with other IP or something?

Thankyou

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token is valid for 2 months (if you request an extended token, otherwise only a few hours). It will remain the same until the user deletes the app from his/her account or changes his/her password. Then you need to re-authenticate by sending the user to FB again through your app.

IP address does not matter.

Comment: it will remain the same token even more than 2 month if user not delete apps in their facebook account, is that true?

Comment: No, it is a different one.